# AWS Medical Comprehend customization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-comprehend

I am currently using AWS Medical Comprehend to extract data from Dr's dictated text. I am trying to extract data to set it into structured form. AWS Medical comprehend is working good at certain level but not extracting all the proper meanings as entity.
i.e. 
Blood Pressure is 126/30 with standing position.

It extracts good for "Blood Pressure" with "126/30"  as TEST Value. but along with it I want additional position attribute that is standing.

Is it possible to modify medical comprehend. If not how can I do such extraction.
Normal comprehend is also not extracting it otherwise I can merge result of both and continue with my process.

I am now trying with adding custom entity for normal comprehend but it requires lot of data dictionary. (min 1000 training documents. which is nearly not possible with all such cases at my end.) Is there any other way?